# Merge my fork with someone else's fork

Tags: git, github

I have forked a repo on Github, another guy forked it too
I want to merge other-guy's branch into my branch
How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose you have the following Github repositories:

- http://www.github.com/mainuser/mainrepo.git (the origin project)
- http://www.github.com/you/yourfork.git (your fork)
- http://www.github.com/other/anotherfork.git (another fork)

If you worked on your fork, you have a local clone clone of your own fork:

```
git clone git@github.com:you/yourfork.git
```

In order to work with the origin project (and the other fork), you have to add the corresponding remotes:

```
git remote add upstream http://www.github.com/mainuser/mainrepo.git
git remote add fork http://www.github.com/other/anotherfork.git
```

With theses remotes, you can get the remote information by fetching:

```
git fetch upstream
git fetch fork
```

Finally, you can merge the work with yours:

```
git merge fork/branch_you_want_to_merge
```

Comment: Note: you can replace the remotes URL with locations using the git protocol, "git://github.com/other/anotherfork.git" for example. It will do the same, but the git protocol is more efficient than the http protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean `branch` rather than fork.

```
git checkout your-branch
git merge other-guys-branch
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to git, I did forked the main repository on github, so that makes it a branch?

Comment: @IlyaD: No, like you said: what you have now is a fork.